# Can Uranium-235 absorb neutrons and become U-238 instead of splitting?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, isotopes, nucleosynthesis

Does that happen, on occasion?  Does anyone know?

I suppose it is quite rare, ... To absorb three neutrons without once fissioning...

Could U-235 absorb three neutrons at once?  Or just one, becoming U-236, then two at once?

Answer (score 4):

Three neutrons at once, no.  But we can look at the probabilities for each step.

Using [these cross sections](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/sigma/) for "thermal" neutrons with energy 25 milli-eV, the total cross section for (n, fission) is about 460 barns, while the cross section for (n, gamma) (that is, capture to U-236) is about 60 barns.  So for every seven or eight fissions, you have one capture to U-236.

For U-236, the cross section for neutron capture (0.3 barn) is much larger than the cross section for fission (0.0028 barn).

For U-237, the cross sections for capture (0.16 b) and fission (0.15 b) are about the same.

So the answer is that, in a reactor that is fissioning a chemically significant amount of uranium, you'll transmute plenty of U-235 to U-238.  The bottleneck is probably U-237, which has a relatively low capture cross section and a short (week-ish) half-life.  The fraction of U-237 that beta-decay to neptunium (which has its own different capture/fission cross sections) are part of the route to plutonium enrichment.

Comment: answer is good, but I think he minimizes the importance of the U-237 beta decay. About 97% of the U-237 is going to beta decay instead of undergoing an (n,gamma) reaction to U-238.  Some of the U-235 will eventually become U-238, but it is a very small amount.

Comment: Isn't the exact fraction sensitive to the neutron flux, and therefore to the details of the reactor design? Or is there a result I don't know where any critical U-235 fuel assembly winds up with the same ratio of n/U?

Comment: I assumed a flux of 10^14, which is probably on the high side.  If the flux is lower, the probability of absorption will be even less.   The cross section for U237 also seems low.

Comment: @NuclearFission what are the units on that flux of 10^14?

Comment: units on flux are neutrons/cm^2/sec  (standard unit in nuclear engineering)